# UBUNTU 11.10 extend screen problem

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors

I used to extend my screen with absolutely no issues on 11.04 but now i'm only able to mirror displays, the error I am getting when I try to extend screen is this:

[image: The error that throws up]

Please help me out with this ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a dual monitor system. I was able to recreate it by changing the suggested nvidia video driver (yours may be different) for the suggested updated one. This prevented me from having an extended monitors and I could only mirror mine as well.

I solved this by stepping back to the driver first installed with ubuntu on first load and this fixed the issue. If you remember updating the video drivers to the newest model or newer, this may be the issue.

Please let us know if this solved it. I am new to ubuntu and would love to get my feet wet by actually figuring something out. lol Good luck!